# Проблема с неразрешенным внешним символом

Tags: c++

Пытаюсь скомпилировать следующий пример:
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28806/SMTP-Client

MSVC выдает ошибки:

```
Ошибка  1   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > __thiscall ECSmtp::GetErrorText(void)const " (?GetErrorText@ECSmtp@@QBE?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@XZ) в функции __catch$_main$0 C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  2   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall CSmtp::CSmtp(void)" (??0CSmtp@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  3   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: virtual __thiscall CSmtp::~CSmtp(void)" (??1CSmtp@@UAE@XZ) в функции _main   C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  4   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::AddRecipient(char const *,char const *)" (?AddRecipient@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD0@Z) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  5   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::AddAttachment(char const *)" (?AddAttachment@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  6   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::AddMsgLine(char const *)" (?AddMsgLine@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main  C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  7   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::Send(void)" (?Send@CSmtp@@QAEXXZ) в функции _main C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  8   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetSubject(char const *)" (?SetSubject@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main  C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  9   error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetSenderName(char const *)" (?SetSenderName@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  10  error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetSenderMail(char const *)" (?SetSenderMail@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  11  error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetReplyTo(char const *)" (?SetReplyTo@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main  C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  12  error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetXMailer(char const *)" (?SetXMailer@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main  C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  13  error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetLogin(char const *)" (?SetLogin@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main  C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  14  error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetPassword(char const *)" (?SetPassword@CSmtp@@QAEXPBD@Z) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  15  error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetXPriority(enum CSmptXPriority)" (?SetXPriority@CSmtp@@QAEXW4CSmptXPriority@@@Z) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  16  error LNK2019: ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall CSmtp::SetSMTPServer(char const *,unsigned short)" (?SetSMTPServer@CSmtp@@QAEXPBDG@Z) в функции _main    C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\test\main.obj  test
Ошибка  17  error LNK1120: неразрешенных внешних элементов: 16  C:\Users\john\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\test\Debug\test.exe test
```

В чем тут проблема? Спасибо.

Comment: Вы наверное не включили в компиляцию какие-то .cpp-файлы.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это ошибка сборки (линковки) проекта - вы подключили заголовки где определен  `CSmtp`, но не реализовали данные методы, либо не подключили соответствующий `.cpp` файл, либо не подключили библиотеку. Если это `.cpp` файл - то просто добавьте их в проект, если библиотека - то вам необходимо указать путь `.lib` файлу в `Project->Properties->Linker->General->Advanced Include Directories` и сам `.lib` файл в `Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies`.